# How can I prevent audiobooks from appearing in Banshee's 'Music' list

Tags: banshee

I have a number of audiobooks in mp3 format which, when imported into Banshee, appear in the Music category. I am able to get them into the Audiobooks category by dragging them over, but that still appear in Music, and when I try to remove them from the Music library, they are also removed from Audiobooks. How can I get them to appear only in Audiobooks?

NB: They are kept in a separate audiobooks folder, away from the music.

Comment: It's not really an answer but I just wanted to add that if your library is really big and you don't want to wait for the rescan you can simply sort all your music by _File location_ column in Banshee, select everything from your `~/Audiobooks` path and drag it to the _Audiobooks_ library section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of importing directly, drop them in the audiobooks folder and then rescan your media library for banshee to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this sorted itself when I restarted Banshee. I guess it just needed a way to refresh the database.

Comment: just click on the rescan media library menu item in `tools`